# IPG v5 or Numerical IPG, What's The Difference? (GAN356X)

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

So I recently bought the GAN356X IPG v5 (stickerless) off of Amazon. When I went to the Gan website, there were two options for GAN356X: IPG v5 and Numerical IPG. On the Gan website it doesn't really specify what the difference is between the two. What concerned me was that the IPG v5 version was cheaper than the Numerical IPG version, and I still don't know the difference.

Comment: I would ask this in the Daily Discussion thread of the /r/Cubers sub-reddit. Maybe someone there knows. I personally am no speedcuber, so I have no idea what the difference between the two cubes is.

Comment: Comparing their descriptions on the SpeedCubeShop webshop, the [IPG v5 version](https://speedcubeshop.com/products/gan-356-x-magnetic-3x3-ipg-v5) and [Numerical IPG version](https://speedcubeshop.com/products/gan-356-x-magnetic-3x3-numerical-ipg) are fairly similar, except that the Numerical IPG version has in addition 3 different tension settings, so the tensions can be adjusted per side. Apart from that, their descriptions seems the same: easily interchangeable magnet system without glue; 4 different GES springs with varying strengths; buttery smooth turning, stability, and corner cutting.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the [Numerical IPG v5](https://shop.gancube.com/product/gan356-x) actually comes with 4 extra sets of tension nuts.

> [Numerical IPG] Equipped with 4 sets of GTN

which are explained (much) later down the page in the section 'The new GES+'.